# Why nestjs service is not injected into passport strategy?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport

I'm trying to make application using nestjs

Dependency injection into controller works well so far.

But when I inject service into passport strategy, injecting is not working.

I want to inject `authService` into `googleStrategy`.

This is my module code.

`auth.modules.ts`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModules,
    PassportModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, GoogleStrategy],
})
export class AuthModules {}
```

`google.strategy.ts`

```js
@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({ /*...*/ });
    console.log(this.authService) //undefined
  }
}
```

In this case, `AuthService` is not injected.

When I inject `AuthService` manually using `@Inject` decorator, `AuthService` injected successfully.

```js
constructor(@Inject('AuthService') private authService: AuthService) {
  super({ /*...*/ });
  console.log(this.authService) // AuthService is injected
}
```

Why service is not injected into passport strategy?

Comment: show us the `AuthService` class; and which version of nest you're using

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? When you manually inject the AuthService (@Inject...) how do you declare in auth.module.ts? I tried doing that but nest wouldn't let me inject the dependency without injecting the module via auth.module.ts

Comment: Getting same error any leads

Answer (score 1):

i think that you want to do something like this

```js
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { UserService } from 'src/user/user.service';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
config();
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
  constructor(private readonly UserSerive: UserService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: process.env.jwt_secret,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return {
      user: payload.sub,
      username: payload.username,
      id: payload.id,
      roles: (await this.UserSerive.findOne(payload.id)).roles,
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to register your `AuthService` in `AuthModule` like this:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: 'AUTH_SERVICE',
    useClass: AuthService
  },
  GoogleStrategy
]
```

And then, in `GoogleStrategy` class, in constructor write this:

```
constructor(@Inject('AUTH_SERVICE') private authService: AuthService)
```